# How to make add a values in column with values based on a list

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

Im working on a dataset which I simplify here.

Suppose I have one data below:

```
col1 <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
col2 <- c("auto", "bike", "car")

data1 <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

And another data below:

```
colA <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
colB <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")

data2 <- data.frame(colA, colB)
```

I would like to add  col2 from data1 as another column in data2 that matches colA. I'd like to use ifelse in a loop but im really confused how to do this. Below is my poor attempt.

```
for(i in data1$col1){
  data2$col2 <- ifelse(data1$col1 == i, data1$col2, NA)
}
```

but im getting this error

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "col2", value = c("auto", NA, NA)) :
replacement has 3 rows, data has 4

Im new in loop. Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: You may need `match` or named vector i.e. `data2$col2 <- setNames(data1$col2, data1$col1)[data2$colA]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `left_join` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(data1, data2, by = c("col1" = "colA"))

#   col1 col2 colB
# 1  AAA auto    1
# 2  BBB bike    2
# 3  CCC  car    3
```

Or alternatively:

```r
left_join(data2, data1, by = c("colA" = "col1"))

#   colA colB col2
# 1  AAA    1 auto
# 2  BBB    2 bike
# 3  CCC    3  car
# 4  DDD    4 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks dcsuka, this works perfectly and thus helps for my particular dataset. But I do also want to learn how to use loop to achieve this. Do you think its possible?

Comment: Yes, but it is much slower, less efficient, and less concise. There is a de facto taboo against for loops in R. If this solution helped you, consider leaving a green check mark so others know it is correct.